# how to shift (indent) yanked lines in vi

Tags: vim, vi

I already know many ways to shift (indent - and autoindent) lines in vi, but I was wondering if it is possible to mark/yank a block of lines and indent them.

I already tried the obvious (esc ma y'a >>) but that didn't work.

Comment: Well, are you confusing "mark" and "yank"? And what you tried doesn't seem obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a confusing question if there is one. Your "obvious" attempt seems more "random" than "obvious":

- you go back to normal mode with `<Esc>`,
- you place mark `a` with `ma`,
- you yank the text from the cursor to mark `a` with `y'a`, which doesn't do anything useful because the cursor is already on mark `a`,
- and then you indent the current line with `>>`.

Which begs a few questions:

- Why do you yank at all?

  Yanking and indenting are completely orthogonal so that `y` has nothing to do here.
- Why do you not move the cursor?

  If you don't move the cursor, then there is no point placing a mark.
- Why do you use `>>`?

  `[count]>>` doesn't know anything about marks: it indents `[count]` lines.

What I *think* you are trying to do is something like this:

```
ma     " place mark a
jjj    " move the cursor to another line
>'a    " indent from current line to mark a
```

Where…

- `ma` is the same `ma` as in your "obvious" attempt,
- `jjj` is just an example motion,
- `>'a` is the operator `>` (not to be confused with `>>`), followed by the motion `'a`.

But you probably don't need marks to begin with:

```
>/foo<CR>    " indent from current line to next line matching foo
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind reply.  This was what I was attempting to do.  Apologies if my way of describing the problem didn't live up to your Paris, France expectations.  

Come on man, have a croissant and a coffee, smell the roses.